# Text Selection using Controller in RichEditBox

Tags: c#, uwp, xbox, gamepad

I am working on a UWP application, that contains a RichEditBox including buttons for text decorations (bold, italic...). The Box is working fine and as expected on Desktop. The app should also run on Xbox allowing users to enter text using the Xbox controller. Is there a possibility to enable text selection for controller input?

[image]
(In this image "st fo" is selected inside the Box on Desktop. Now how to do this on xbox?)

On Desktop, users may simply hold shift and select text but I could not find an integrated support similar to that. I was thinking about eventually mapping two buttons for start/end of selection and then select text programmatically but I am not sure if this is possible in UWP.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a possibility to enable text selection for controller input?

By the Xbox controller, you could try to press and hold the `A` button and at the same time manipulate the left stick for moving to select.